# Find Range of $a$ if $ \lfloor \frac{1}{3}+2a \sin ^3 x \rfloor $ is an Even function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, symmetric-functions

Find Range of $a$ if $$ f(x)= \lfloor \frac{1}{3}+2a \sin ^3 x \rfloor $$ is an Even function

My try:

we have $$f(-x)=f(x)$$ $\implies$

$$ \lfloor \frac{1}{3}+2a \sin ^3 x \rfloor=\lfloor \frac{1}{3}-2a \sin ^3 x \rfloor \tag{1}$$

Obviously $a=0$ is the possibility

Now how can we determine other values of $a$ which makes $(1)$ True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is symmetric in $a$ and trivial for $a=0$, so we can just examine $a>0$:

Suppose $2a\leq \tfrac13$, then
$$\bigg\lfloor\frac13+\underbrace{2a\sin^3x}_{\in [-\tfrac13,\tfrac13]}\bigg\rfloor
= 0
= \bigg\lfloor\frac13-\underbrace{2a\sin^3x}_{\in [-\tfrac13,\tfrac13]}\bigg\rfloor$$

Suppose $2a>\tfrac13$, then at $x = \tfrac\pi2$

$$\bigg\lfloor\frac13+2a\sin^3 \tfrac\pi2\bigg\rfloor
= \bigg\lfloor\frac13+2a\bigg\rfloor \geq 0,$$
but
$$\bigg\lfloor\frac13-2a\sin^3 \tfrac\pi2\bigg\rfloor
= \bigg\lfloor\frac13 -2a\bigg\rfloor < 0.$$
Hence $a \in [-\tfrac16,\tfrac16]$.

Answer (score 2):

We need $f\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=f\left(+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.  Therefore,
$$\left\lfloor \frac{1}{3}+2a\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\frac{1}{3}-2a\right\rfloor\,.$$
If $|a|> \dfrac{1}{6}$, then one of the numbers $\frac{1}{3}-2a$ and $\frac{1}{3}+2a$ is negative, while the other is positive, so the equality above does not happen.  What happens if $|a|\leq\dfrac{1}{6}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $z = 2a \sin^3 x$, then we need to find when
$
   \left\lfloor \frac 13 - z \right\rfloor 
   = \left\lfloor \frac 13 + z \right\rfloor
$?

We suppose first that $z$ is an integer. Then we get

\begin{align}
   \left\lfloor \frac 13 - z \right\rfloor 
   &= \left\lfloor \frac 13 + z \right\rfloor
\\
   \left\lfloor \frac 13 \right\rfloor - z
   &= \left\lfloor \frac 13 \right\rfloor + z
\\
   z &= 0 
\end{align}

So, if $z$ is not an integer, we can suppose that $0 < z < 1$.

Hence
$
   \left\lfloor \frac 13 - z \right\rfloor =
   \begin{cases}
       0 & \text{If $0 < z \le \dfrac 13$} \\
      -1 & \text{If $\dfrac 13 < z < 1$} \\
   \end{cases}
$

and
$
   \left\lfloor \frac 13 + z \right\rfloor =
   \begin{cases}
       0 & \text{If $0 < z < \dfrac 23$} \\
       1 & \text{If $\dfrac 23 < z < 1$} \\
   \end{cases}
$

We can conclude that we need

\begin{align}
   |z| &\le \dfrac 13 \\
   |2a \sin^3 x| &\le \dfrac 13 \\
   2|a| &\le \dfrac 13 &\text{(Since $\max |\sin^3 x| = 1$}) \\
   |a| &\le \dfrac 16
\end{align}